# Почему можно вызвать функцию в ее определении?

Tags: c++

У нас есть функция `foo()`:

```
 bool foo(int a)
    {
        if (a == 3)
        {
            foo(a+1);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Почему мы можем ее вызвать прямо в определении?

Comment: Это рекурсия называется. Это просто так работает.

Comment: это называется [рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%92_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Ответ смотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221027/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: А почему - нет?...

Comment: @gbg Отсутствие условия выхода - потому что у нас тут StackOverflow?

Comment: чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно понять рекурсию

Comment: Задайте себе другой вопрос -- ***"а почему это могло бы не получиться?"***

Answer (score 2):

Вызов функции из самой себя называется *рекурсией*. Понятно, что для обеспечения работоспособности такого кода должно быть достижимо условие завершения рекурсии. Иначе (при заведомо ограниченном объеме памяти) программа грохнется с переполнением стека (Stack overflow).

Для С++ рекурсивный вызов разрешён для любых функций кроме `main`. [Ссылка на черновик стандарта](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#13):

> Recursive calls are permitted, except to the `main` function

Comment: Однако, если написать `int (*f)(int, char **) = main;`, то тоже можно

Comment: @avp почему вы так решили?

Comment: Просто написал кодик. `g++ t.cpp && ./a.out` и увидел / (На самом деле, исходя из самых общих сображений, я в этом и не сомневался)

Comment: @avp не сомневались в чём? Что можно скомпилировать код, не соответствующий стандарту языка, и получить какой-то результат, кажущийся нормальным? Я всё же рассчитывал, что вы в курсе того, что такое неопределённое поведение, что конкретные компиляторы на конкретных машинах могут работать не так, как описывает стандарт и т.п.

Comment: Я уже неоднокатно говорил, что делать с такими стандартами (и их создателями)

Comment: @avp буквально сегодня видел комментарий, что "опираться на UB это примерно как быть драг-диллером, вроде как выгодное занятие, но всё же могут однажды поймать".

Comment: Чем дальше, тем больше UB в С++ и программирование на нем это поход по льду в переменчивую погоду. Истину говорят злые языки -- С++ хорош для экономики, он постоянно создает новые рабочие места

Comment: Кстати, g++ при взятии адреса функции `main` [выдаёт предупреждение](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b2aed800a1f5d46): "warning: ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main'". Но кому нужны эти предупреждения компилятора, работает же всё :D